# Is it possible to have the <kbd> for the comma enlarged?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design, fonts

I was answering a post that involved the key combos `ctrl+,` and `ctrl+,`. I was going to use the `<kbd>` tags, but they look the same for `.` and `,` - or at least too close for me to tell the difference without sitting 3 inches from the screen.

Is it possible to get this changed?

Example:

<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>  (this is a comma)

<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> (this is a period)

Screen resolution is 1920x1080, it's the same in Chrome and Edge

[image]

Comment: You might want to include a screenshot of what you see. I can clearly tell the difference between the `,` and `.` looking at your question.

Comment: The difference does look really slight, esp. on my not-top-class laptop screen. I can tell the difference here, but it might be because I know what should be there.

Comment: I can't see the difference on my 1366x768px laptop unless I zoom to 500%, and on my 1920x1680 monitor, the difference is still tiny at 150%.

Comment: How about if we use another font instead...

Comment: This probably applies to more sites than just Unix. Maybe this belongs on [meta.se]?

Answer (score 30):

For discussion, a possible improvement:

[image: big comma key screenshot]

The above is a screenshot, created with

```
<kbd><div style="transform-origin:bottom;transform:scale(3) translateY(0.4ex)">,</div></kbd>
```

For something that's supposed to look like a comma *key*, there's no reason for it to be proportional to the size of the letters on a letter key. Why *not* blow it up so it occupies half of the available space? (The only reason not to occupy *all* the space is to avoid confusion with the apostrophe key)

CSS transforms are tricky, so this isn't a great solution. But ignoring the implementation difficulty, I wanted to put this out there to demonstrate emphatic agreement that the current font is way WAY **WAY** too small.

Comment: Scaling up one-character strings would be a nice solution, especially if it works with letters and numbers as well.

Comment: I've *sorta* fixed it with this CSS: `kbd {margin: 0 .1em; padding: 0px .6em; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px;}`. Sadly, there aren't many ways to style a single character. SE would have to rely on external libraries (http://letteringjs.com/ for example) or do something quite hacky, such as using `data-*` attributes with the content, and styling only the keys with a few elements.

Comment: How does this work with other characters, or with multiple characters (like your `alt`, for example)?

Comment: It wouldn't work with multiple characters. I'm suggesting that if we want the keys to look *good*, the markdown processor needs to do something a lot smarter than just pass through kbd tags into the HTML output. It could potentially use a lookup table to find the best rendering method for each single character.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley `kbd[data-key=","]{}`? Then the CSS could do the hard work, and the markdown would only require a special case for the quotes (i.e. use the other type of quote around it).

Answer (score 5):

There is a solution without resorting to JS libraries or CSS hacks. If you bold the characters, they become slightly larger, making the distinction between `.` and `,` more obvious.

Normal vs. **bold**:
<kbd>,</kbd> <kbd>.</kbd>
<kbd>**,**</kbd> <kbd>**.**</kbd>

```
<kbd>,</kbd> <kbd>.</kbd>  
<kbd>**,**</kbd> <kbd>**.**</kbd>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want, you can use something like this: <sub><sub>[image: ,]</sub></sub>

Here's an in-line comparison: <kbd>,</kbd> <sub><sub>[image: ,]</sub></sub>

Here's the code:

```
<sub><sub><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lrzd0.png" alt=","></sub></sub>
```

Why `<sub>` twice? Here's why: [image: ,] (it isn't in the same line!)

---

The image is a png with exactly 261 bytes. Here's it in base64:

> data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABIAAAATCAMAAACqTK3AAAAAWlBMVEXh4+X///+ts7nOz8/t7/DBxci1usAkJynf39/Z296Bx+Xu7uXh493UqmmnYynu+Pzc9ffh4/Ds4+Wj0+V2ueXh49Mqcbvh0bD/5K5Td64kJ1GaWyl1RylaJynnr9rlAAAAZklEQVQY05XQORKDMBBE0W6Z0WKMbfb9/tckIECaoqD44YtmGgzWRNlABMkYlUmA3eUwC0MiijSPqJ2da1L6fJ1731LJYVUEFFOtqF+6XFEx/itFP+YXp569LXocgZd0QvGgfyV5bm+YA6elnAiSAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC

---

**Disclamer**: I've made the image in PNG by taking a printscreen of an oversized coma (30px) by using the element inspector. The image itself was made using MSPaint and optimized using https://tinypng.com/. The double `<ub>` was an attempt to fix the problem of the image being in weird positions. And may not work in every browser! (It doesn't work in IE11.)