# Is it possible to modify visual rendering of links locally?

Tags: support, user-interface

I can't see links in the text of questions and answers on the main site. They are simply invisible to me ("invisible" = "indistinguishable from ordinary text").

Is there a way I could apply some sort of local stylesheet to make them stand out (possibly by underlining them), preferably while at the same time not modifying the links on the Meta site (which are *good*) or any other unrelated site?

I'm currently accessing the site through Chrome.

Sorry, but I'm a bit lost when it comes to CSS and graphical interfaces in general.

---

Update: The links on the main site are now underlined by default.

Comment: I would prefer a javascript skin kind of social fixer. Funcionalities whished: change colours, hide top bar, hide left bar, hide questions from users with rep < 300.

Comment: Related: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4939/could-the-link-colours-within-post-text-be-made-to-stand-out-more-from-regular-t

Comment: Yes, you can do it with custom CSS. There used to be a Firefox and Chrome extension called Stylish that made it relatively easy, but unfortunately it got hijacked into distributing spyware, and I don't know if a replacement has emerged yet.

Comment: @Gilles stylus, not as full-featured, but works well enough for me: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylus/clngdbkpkpeebahjckkjfobafhncgmne?hl=en https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/styl-us/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about a user script?

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name unix.stackexchange obvious link
// @version 0.01
// @include /https?\:\/\/unix.stackexchange\.com\/questions.*
// @grant none
// ==/UserScript==

function addCss(cssString) {
    var newCss = document.createElement('style');
    newCss.type = "text/css";
    newCss.innerHTML = cssString;
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(newCss);
}

addCss (
    '.post-text a {text-decoration: underline;}'
);
```

The bulk of this script came from [here](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/3362-stackexchange-obvious-followed-link-color/code).

As an FYI: I use [Tampermonkey](https://tampermonkey.net/) in Chrome to run user scripts.

Thanks so much for the question.  This has been annoyance for a while, but never to the level of doing something about it...

Comment: Thanks! Tampermonkey with the given script does work very well!

Comment: The answer above worked well, but is now obsolete since the links on the main site now are underlined by default.