# Difference between "foo" and “foo”, 'foo' and ‘foo’ — and -- as well

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, title

Look at [this title](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/457398/can-someone-explain-the-meaning-of-and-in-a-linux-unix-command):

[image: mangled dashes]

The meaning of a long dash? Ah, no, it's `--`, correctly spelled in the title, but mangled in the title, which means that it's mangled in search engine results too. Or look at [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/437965/why-doesnt-alias-foo-echo-this-is-a-quote-work):

[image: mangled quotes]

Well, it won't work if you use `“` and `”`: only ASCII characters such as `"` have a special effect. Oh, wait, once again that's just because Stack Exchange mangled the title, so it looks wrong on the site and in search engine results.

This is a technical site. We have a lot of questions about [shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shell) [quoting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quoting) and [options](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/options). Exact punctuation is important.

I raised this a long time ago, and [the response from a Stack Exchange developer](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3429/site-design-updates/3432#comment5263_3432) was

> We looked at the quotes on the last several hundred posts. While a few would be more correct without fancy quotes, the vast majority are correct and would be negatively impacted by such a change. Given that, we want to stick with the net-positive of replacing the quotes globally.

Yeah, no, that doesn't make sense. Saying that replacing the quotes is “net-positive” doesn't make it so. It's a cosmetic improvement that can be done manually, versus mangling that affects the meaning and can't be bypassed. Please stop mangling punctuation in titles.

Comment: So true. Plus I feel offended when any site, text editor or whatever "knows better" what **I** want to write. The technical aspect should matter the most; but hello! if I cannot even make it stop, this is rude and haughty.

Comment: I agree whole-heartedly. A couple of years ago, I came across this particular bug on [so] and suggested that [Smarty-like formatting of titles be disabled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/273730/229493) (at least on programming sites). When informed that this behavior was by design, I changed my bug report to a feature request - to no avail. You make a good, solid case in this post so I hope you get a better response than I did.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

We have now disabled all [Smarty](https://daringfireball.net/projects/smartypants/)-like modifications text in titles.

From now on, the title text saved for the post is the title text that will be displayed.

If folks want em-dashes (`ALT-0151`) and fancy quotes (`ALT-0145` through `-0148`) to appear in titles, they are welcome to add them. But we won’t convert it automatically any longer.

> we’re no longer the
> smarty-pants who makes changes
> to typography

Comment: Thank you! But if I understand correctly, previously entered titles remain in their modified glyph form, right?

Comment: @AdminBee No, the transformation was done on display, the database contains the correct title. So now the title of [Why doesn't alias foo='echo "This is a quote: \'"' work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/437965/why-doesnt-alias-foo-echo-this-is-a-quote-work) is rendered sensibly.

Comment: Ok, that's great!

Comment: What's ALT-0151? 151 (in decimal) seems to be the windows-1252 encoding of the U+2014 character (em-dash). Is that how you enter those characters on some deployments of MS Windows?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, yes.