# TAB not preserved in code blocks

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bug, status-review, formatting

Mangling code or tab separated data:

```
This    is  tab delimited   data
```

---

Rendering of code blocks break tabs.

This is bad for example

- for code that require tabs ([Example](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC1040)).
- for posts where users paste `tab` delimited data.
- <sub>and in general ... rude :P</sub>

When respondents copy the data or code from a question they get spaces instead of tabs, even if questioner has used tabs. If one click edit the tabs are present, but not in the HTML rendering. Code snippets also get a four space indentation where tab is used.

Should `tab`s be preserved or at least be an opt out?

CSS has [tab-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/tab-size) which can be used as a optional configuration for those who want 1 or 32 spaces per tab or what ever :P

https://caniuse.com/?search=tab-size

Comment: This is particularly important for us since a lot of the questions we get are about parsing text files and having the actual tabs in the example input we copy/paste is essential.

Comment: While I hope the [meta-tag:status-review] tag means the developers are considering this, it seems to [have been status-declined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/294874/410681) in the past. The available [workaround](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/294870/410681) is quite inconvenient, but unlikely to go away.

Comment: @fra-san the status-review was added by me and it only puts this on the devs' radar. They will eventually look at it and then either choose to implement it or not, but the [meta-tag:status-review] doesn't mean anything other than one of the local mod team (me, in this case) felt this was something they should escalate to SE.